# Why isn't this theme applying to my app?

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-manifest

I'm new to Android development. I want my app to have a Material Design look/feel, so I tried adding this to my Android manifest file:

```
<application
  android:label="Repository"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material"
>
</application>
```

However, after applying this, the app looks the same when I debug it. I haven't explicitly specified the colors for the activity bar / background / etc. in any of the layout files, so I don't know why this would happen. Is there anything else that I should be doing?

**edit:** I am testing with an API level 24 Android device.

Comment: What is "the same"? How do you know it's _not_ working? Maybe post a screenshot of what you see and a sample of what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
@android:style/Theme.Material
```

requires API Level 21+

better use your styles.xml and extend the theme to your AppTheme (if you want to customize )

example :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material">
    <item name="colorAccent">#ffc423</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#081d5c</item>
    [...]
</style>
```

manifest.xml

```
<application
          [...]
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

hope my answer could help you

Comment: I just checked and I am using API level 24.

Answer (score 0):

To get the material theme effective on lower version of android as well you can apply this theme in the manifest. Define your color in colors.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```